# Sumifs with between dates

Tags: date, between, sumifs

I'm trying to write this formula:
=SUMIFS(Data!$D:$D,Data!$S:$S,"<=31/12/2019",Data!R:R,"<=31/12/2017")

where column S contains (UK formatted dd/mm/yyyy) dates but I need only the dates between 01/11/2017 and 31/12/2017 - how can I write this with SUMIFS?

Any help would be very much appreciated! Many thanks!!

Comment: I found the answer here: https://exceljet.net/formula/sum-if-date-is-between

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: exceljet.net/formula/sum-if-date-is-between